# select Date picker popup not coming for each row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table in my form (i have multiple rows in it) for first-row input click hijiri date picker popup showing but for other 
rows input clicked date picker popup not coming

this is my code

```
<table class="table"  id="tableId">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Card Expiry</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="IQ in IQGridUpdates">
<td>
<div>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="CardExpH1Date"  on-click="showCal2();" maxlength="12"  ng-model=IQ.CardExpH1Date/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>



<script type="text/javascript">

function showCal2() {
$('#CardExpH1Date').calendarsPicker({
 calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
}


</script>
```

Comment: Not Working ,Datepicker popup not getting

Answer (score 0):

The ID you are using an each row should be unique. When you iterate the array in HTML, ensure the id attribute of input element hold an unique value

It should be something like below, now each input element will hold a unique ID, hence each trigger will call the function

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="IQ in IQGridUpdates">
   <td>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  **id="CardExpH1Date_{{$index}}"**  on-click="showCal2();" maxlength="12"  ng-model=IQ.CardExpH1Date/>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Not Working ,Datepicker popup not getting

Comment: Can you post what you tried, Did you add the index to your ID attribute?

Comment: Remove your Jquery code to trigger this calendarpicker inside the showCal2 function as the ID wont be found anymore. Just you have to have the oncall event function and trigger the calendar picker

Answer (score 0):

You need to give different `id` for each input type. Assuming IQ has an unique data in it like `IQ.id` something.

```
<table class="table"  id="tableId">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Card Expiry</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="IQ in IQGridUpdates">
<td>
<div>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="IQ.id"  on-click="showCal2(IQ.id);" maxlength="12"  ng-model=IQ.CardExpH1Date/>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>



<script type="text/javascript">

function showCal2(id) {
$('#id').calendarsPicker({
 calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
}


</script>
```

Comment: Not Working ,Datepicker popup not getting

Answer (score 0):

I am confused what this code mean and I think it is nonsense. if you need a date picker input, you just put the code

```
<script>
    $('#CardExpH1Date').calendarsPicker({
     calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
</script>
```

and remove the 'on click' in your code.
it isn't necessary to use 'onclick' in this case because it is supported by jQuery Calendars Datepicker.

[You can find more here](http://keith-wood.name/calendarspicker.html)

Comment: Not Working ,Datepicker popup not getting

Comment: did you include the :
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>

and 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.calendars.picker.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>

as in my recommended link ?